# The email address is badly formatted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

**I am trying to login at firebase by using react. I created manually email address and password at Firebase Authentication. When I am trying to login that email address I got error: "The email address is badly formatted."**

**Here is my firebase config**

```
import firebase from "firebase";

const app = {
  apiKey: "-----------",
  authDomain: "userauth-f1874.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://userauth-f1874.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "userauth-f1874",
  storageBucket: "userauth-f1874.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1047612050312",
  appId: "1:1047612050312:web:393f32f6a7fe77a4fa083d",
  measurementId: "G-S5ZQF9VK49"
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const config = firebase.initializeApp(app);

export default config;
```

**Here is my react Signin component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import config from "../components/config/config";

    const Signin = () => {
      const [state, setState] = useState({
        email: "",
        password: ""
      });

      const submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        config
          .auth()
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(state.email, state.password)
          .catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            if (errorCode === "auth/wrong-password") {
              alert("Wrong password.");
            } else {
              alert(errorMessage);
            }
            console.log(error);
          });
      };

      return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <div className="fields">
              <label htmlFor="email">email</label>
              <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="email" />
            </div>
            <div className="fields">
              <label htmlFor="password">password</label>
              <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password" />
            </div>
            <button>Signin</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default Signin;
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you are sending that results in this message?

Comment: But actually log `state.email` and show us what is being sent to `signInWithEmailAndPassword(...)` in the submit handler